# htmlentities content that has HTML

Tags: php, codeigniter, multilingual

I'm trying to support multiple languages on my site. Some of the content that needs translating will have entity references like `Ç`. I could use `htmlentities` to convert that into a `&Atilde;`. However, what if I need to translate a string that has mark up:

```
"<p>Hello, <a href="">world with Ç</a></p>"
```

If I use `htmlentities`, the `<` and `>` would be converted, too. I don't want to break down the string into tags and non-tag parts, then apply `htmlentities` only to the non-tag parts. That'll be too messy and tedious.

Comment: How about using a Unicode encoding like UTF-8?

Comment: I keep seeing weird characters in IE. I'll look into UTF-8 angle.

Comment: You need to [properly specify the document’s character encoding](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/charset.html#h-5.2.2).

Comment: I looked at the response headers and saw this for the HTML: `text/html; charset=UTF-8`. I'm not setting this in the mark up. My .htaccess has `AddDefaultCharset UTF-8`. So I am already in UTF-8. IE doesn't support `&apos;`, so I started using `&#39;`. This got me thinking about other characters.

Comment: And despite the charset being UTF-8, when I try to display, say, `Ç` on my web pages, it appears as a black diamond with a question mark in it.

Answer (score 1):

A work around posted [here](http://af-design.com/blog/2010/08/17/escaping-unicode-characters-to-html-entities-in-php/)

Pass your string to the following function and work with the returned string.

```
  function unicode_escape_sequences($str){
      $working = json_encode($str);
      $working = preg_replace('/\\\u([0-9a-z]{4})/', '&#x$1;', $working);
      return json_decode($working);
  }
```